# EXC_BAD_ACCESS NSUrlConnection

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I perform the last line of the function (webData).

```
-(void)requestSoap{
NSString *requestUrl = @"http://www.website.com/webservice.php";
NSString *soapMessage = @"the soap message";
//website and soapmessage are valid in original code.

 NSError **error;
 NSURLResponse *response;

 //Convert parameter string to url
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl];
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

 NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

 //Create an XML message for webservice
 [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 NSData *webData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:error];
}
```

I tried not to release a thing, because what I read on the net is it's almost always a memory thing.

When I debug the code `(NSZombieEnabled = YES)` this is what I get:

```
[Session started at 2010-05-31 15:56:13 +0200.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1461.2) (Fri Mar  5 04:43:10 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 19856.
test(19856) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
test(19856) malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks
test(19856) malloc: process 19832 no longer exists, stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack-logs.19832.test.w9Ek4L.index
test(19856) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.19856.test.URRpQF.index
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: the "NSError **error" seems as if there is a * too much.

Also when passing the error to the "send synchronous" pas it as the &error to store the address of the error.

Comment: Using a series of breakpoints you could determine exactly which line is causing the EXEC_.

Comment: > he "NSError **error" seems as if there is a * too much. Also when passing the error to the "send synchronous" pas it as the &error to store the address of the error.

Just great RickiG, i just didnt see it. What a blooper.

Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the definition of the `error` variable. You should use

```
NSError *error;
```

instead of

```
NSError **error; // There is a '*' too much here
```

Then, when you pass it to the `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` you should pass its address using `&error`:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                      returningResponse:&response
                                  error:&error];
```